# Replacing java -Xlog from java 8 to java 17

Tags: java-8, java-17

I am trying to update logging framework -Xlog from java 8 to java 17

This is the one used in java 8 version:

```
JVM_LOG="-Xloggc:./logs/${COMPONENT_TAG}-GC.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:+PrintGCCause -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=2 -XX:GCLogFileSize=5M"
```

I have updated it to java 17 as follows:

```
JVM_LOG="-Xlog:logging=debug:time,level,tags::filecount=2,filesize=5M -Xlog:gc*=debug:file=./logs/${COMPONENT_TAG}-GC.log -Xlog:age*=debug"
```

But it seems despite I use debug option, not a lot of logs are printed as opposed to java 8 version which prints quite a lot of logs.

But when I separate the filecount and following part into separate flag, I see lots of lines printing.

```
JVM_LOG="-Xlog:logging=debug:time,level,tags -Xlog::::filecount=2,filesize=5M -Xlog:gc*=debug:file=./logs/${COMPONENT_TAG}-GC.log -Xlog:age*=debug"
```

Is the way I mapped wrong? What is the correct mapping I should utilize?

I utilized this guide: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/java.htm#GUID-BE93ABDC-999C-4CB5-A88B-1994AAAC74D5__CONVERTGCLOGGINGFLAGSTOXLOG-A5046BD1

**EDIT:**

I tried to do as in this page (https://confluence.atlassian.com/confkb/unrecognized-jvm-gc-options-when-using-java-11-1002472841.html). But still not seeing detailed logs as in java 8.

```
JVM_LOG="-Xlog:gc*,gc+age*=trace:file=./logs/${COMPONENT_TAG}-GC.log:tags,time,uptime,level:filecount=2,filesize=5M"
```